# ASP.net simple question : uploading code behind changes to new server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dev server, and a live server.  I make a change to the code behind on the dev server, and upload the files to the live server, but nothing changes.

I know I'm being dense, but what do I need to do?  I've tried restarting the app pool, restarting the website etc but no luck!

If I make changes to the aspx file, this works, but any changes in the cs file and nothing happens.

Comment: what code. Does it live in the App_Code folder, or do you need to compile an assembly?

Comment: If possible, publish directly to where necessary, or it this is too risky, maybe on your dev server, and then copy it across (same effect, but allows sanity testing and confidence first)  Also if doing this be wearing of Web config and other files that might differ between environments.

Comment: It's just in the virtual directory, the aspx page and cs page are the ones i'm uploading to the new location.

Comment: How did you get the code live in the first place? Was it by using the Visual Studio publish web site wizard? If so, your code is now compiled into a site dll and therefore uploading .cs changes will not work as the site will be referenced the compiled assembly instead.

Comment: If I rename the codebehind.cs file on the live server, the page still runs fine?!?!?!1

Comment: I press build and then run on the local server which works, can't see any DLL

Comment: Then I manually copy + paste the files via FTP to the new location

Comment: Yeah, but if you are running locally you aren't creating a published version of the site. The behaviour of changing the cs file names without seeing any change on actual site sounds like this is what's happening. 

If you change something in the aspx / ascx files do you see a change on the outputted page?

Comment: When I originally published to live server I just copied and pasted the lot, and set up the virtual directory as application, it worked fine.  I don't understand this!  How can I get the changes to work?

Comment: Changing the ASPX page changes yes.

Comment: When I delete the .cs file it still runs!?!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish the website in VS, and upload the published folder including the DLL in the bin folder.